# NightmareJS doesn't return anything to the terminal?

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I copy pasted the example on [Github](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare):

**app.js:**

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');

vo(function* () {
  var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
  var link = yield nightmare
    .goto('http://yahoo.com')
    .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
    .click('.searchsubmit')
    .wait('.ac-21th')
    .evaluate(function () {
      return document.getElementsByClassName('ac-21th')[0].href;
    });
  yield nightmare.end();
  return link;
})(function (err, result) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(result);
});
```

I did: `npm install nightmare vo`

Then `node --harmony app.js` but nothing outputs:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/nightmarejs$ node --harmony app.js
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/nightmarejs$
```

No error messages whatsoever. What can be the problem?

(I'm running node v5.2.0 on Ubuntu.)

Comment: Are you running nightmare headlessly?

Answer (score 1):

Two part answer:

1. Yahoo changed some of their internal naming around.  Nightmare is (as the time of this answer) not great about excepting when actions on nonexistent elements fail, as with your example.  The problem with Yahoo's names was reported in [#490](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/490) and fixed in [#491](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/pull/491).  From the fix:

   ```
   var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
   var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

   nightmare
     .goto('http://yahoo.com')
     .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
     .click('#uh-search-button')
     .wait('#main')
     .evaluate(function () {
       return document.querySelector('#main .searchCenterMiddle li a').href
     })
     .end()
     .then(function (result) {
       console.log(result)
     });
   ```
2. If you're running headlessly (eg, under Crouton or on DigitalOcean or with Docker), I would encourage you to have a look at [#224](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/224).  This also may produce the errant behavior you're seeing.